# HtmlDocument cannot be converted to HtmlDocument

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]

**What does this mean?**

Edit :- I'm using `Agility` Pack

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like the following:

```
    Dim elementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each html As HtmlElement In elementCollection
        'Do your coding here
    Next
```

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using Agility Pack. I guess your code isn't relevant to it. Thank you for your answer.